# Navigate page from header to an other page in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am implementing mobile website. But i cant redirect to page from header part. I want to navigate login page after click on login link.
[image]

After click on i want navigate to other page without reloading.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="padding-top:0;">  
 <span  class="phn-hdr" style="float:right;  font-size: 12px !important;"> 
      <a href="#pagetwo" style="background:#c22222;padding:0px 10px 0 0;color:#fff; text-shadow: none; border:0;" data-ajax="false">Login</a> 
 </span>
</div>
```

As per my knowledge data-role="header" but i am using data-role="page" to navigation.

I want to navigate to an other page.

Comment: You can use JavaScript to help you simulate new pages but showing and bidding sections of your page based on the link clicked.

Comment: It is possible we can open right side panel also (Like left side panel.)??

Comment: Of course. Almost everything is possible with JavaScript. :)